# User shown twice under "Top answer scores" of collectives

Tags: bug, status-completed, collectives

On the Google Cloud Collective's [members page](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/google-cloud?tab=members), a user (me in this case) may be listed twice like this:

[image]

My best guess would be "Top answer scores" also includes upvotes from *Articles* but is listed after top 5 users based on upvotes for answers instead of (ideally) listing the user only once with a total score from answers and articles. So this is also a "Top article scores" list.

Comment: It also seems strange that users would be listed but have +0.

Comment: Thanks for reporting, this is not intentional, I'll have our team look into what might be causing the duplicate (and +0) issue and then hopefully plan for a fix soon.

Comment: @Dharmaraj first: congrats on being the top answer scorer for Google Cloud this week! You are exactly right in your guess:  There are two sidebar widgets on that page: "Top question scorers" and "Top answer scorers", but we collect top question, answer and article scorers for the week and lump answer and articles together.  We'll get that fixed and include only positive-scoring users.

Comment: And for those playing along: the "0" rep users were a case of net-zero score (ie: the upvotes were cancelled out by the downvotes), but the sidebars are incorrectly calculating the rep impact of those.  So it's showing you have a "0" score for the Article you created this week, but your actual rep was +8 (+10 for the upvote, -2 for the downvote).  Gonna fix that too.

Comment: @JohnM.Wright from my understanding, the top "answer/question" questions is just `((numberOfUpvotes - downvotes) * 10)` unlike the actual reputation gain (including +15s for answer accepts) shown for recognized members only on collective [home page](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/google-cloud). Not sure if that was intended.

Comment: You're correct, and that's not the right logic.  The main leaderboard correctly looks at rep history to determine the actual rep earned during the period.  The sidebar widgets took a shortcut -- that was incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for the bug report. The sidebar widgets should now correctly calculate reputation earned from posts created within the last week. Top scores from articles are now contained in a separate widget.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Total reputation earned seems much better than number of upvotes * 10.